# Apache: Prevent PDF-File with non-pdf-extension from opening

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm quite new to setting up a server, so I have a XAMP / Apache 2 related question:

When I rename the extension of a PDF-File to **.txt** all browsers open the PDF as plain text (which I understand and which is good).

**BUT:**

**When I rename the pdf-extension to .jpggggg, it still opens as a PDF!**

WHY??

Because I'm afraid that someone uploads a valid PDF with a hidden exe in it and tricks me into doubleclciking it (which installs a virus/backdoor/anything else on my server or ruis it) .

**So how can in manage to filter such "PDFs with a .exe/.app in it" out?**

Infos for you:

--> Apache VErsion is 2.4
--> The Default Mime-Type is set to plain text!

--> I already deactivated the **mime_magic** Module from loading (by starting the line with **#**    (#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so))

--> And I also deactivated the other line with MIMEMagic in it (# MIMEMagicFile "conf/magic").

(I unfortunately had no other idea than deactivationg the MimeMagic-Module!)

What else can I do!

**So my questions are:**

**1.  Why do ALL the Browsers (Chrome, IE 8, Firefox) handle the file as a PDF although the extion is set ".jpggggg" and how can I prevent this behavior.**

**2. HOW CAN I USE PHP TO FILTER OUT A VALID PDF WHICH HAS AN EXE IN IT**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Tine

Comment: Actually what you call "good", that the "three chars dot extension" in a file name determines how a file is opened under MS-Windows systems is a relict of the 80th and not making sense any more. Modern systems behave different: since the file _still_ contains a pdf, even if you rename it, it is still opened as a pdf file which clearly makes sense. In fact MS-Windows is inconsistent in this: some parts implement the outdated, some the modern behaviour.

Comment: @arkascha: Okay, I see. But how can I PREVENT this. (It's for security reasons: I don't want to end up open a file with a "good" extension, which afterwards turns out to be a PDF-File (because PDF-Files can contain exe-Files and can automatically start these "internal/hidden" exe-Files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, considering your emphasis as a reaction to my comment that all you ask is how you can achieve something like what you sketched in your question here some more information. Best of my knowledge, though certainly other opinions exist:

To prevent a client system to "open" a downloaded file *at the moment of download* you can (and should anyway) implement your own handler for the download. Meaning: the request for the file is *not* handled directly by the http server directly delivering any file found in the file system. Instead the request is handled by some script. That script can do a number of things: check the existence of the file, permissions to download, type of file (real or faked) and, most important, it can send to the client whatever information you desire. In this case this would be a http content type header claiming that was is to follow is a plain text file. The browser (*not the client system*) will accept that and deal accordingly. You can also force the browser to save the payload file instead of attempting to open it right away.

However that does not solve the problem you address at all. It jumps to short. Because in the end the file is on the client system, and that system acts according to its own logic when handing a locally stored file. If the file is for example a PDF and it is asked to open it, then it will do so (except for MS-Windows, where this actually depends on *how* you give the command to open it). You *cannot* prevent that, since this is client side logic you have no control about. Except maybe by crippling the file which makes the whole point of downloading and even handling the file at all obsolete.

So this approach simply suggests a wrong feeling of "security" which it does not offer. Look at it this way: what point is there in trying to prevent opening of such a PDF file (holding an executable inside)? The only way to keep this scenario really safe is to not have the file at all. Because what is the point of having the file disguised superficially as something else? It has not value that way.

Instead you should think about *real* solutions for this issue:

- not accepting PDFs carrying such embedded code in the first place
- use of PDF interpreters (viewing programs) that are not that stupid to actually run untrusted code (I know, all world claims one does need Adobe/Acrobat Reader to open a PDF which obviously is a) total nonsense and b) probably one of the worst choices as a PDF interpreter)
- use an operating system on the cient side that is more secure than MS-Windows. "exe" style executable files are somethjing limited to the MS-Windows world. No other operating system can make use of them (not directly anyway). So embedding such things in a wrapper format like PDF never makes sens in a respectable business anyway. It is just too limited and short sighted. I know, the majority of people *does* use MS-Windows, especially in certain fields of business. But you cannot make their choice of an insecure environment magically more secure.

To round things up: you try to introduce a security step that does not offer any real security but just lures into some kind of safe feeling on a superficial level. Don't do that, it is contra productive. Either solve the issue by blocking such content or rely on people to know what they want and to know what they are doing. Don't try to outsmart everyone. You can't.

Just my two cents...

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. But it seems I did not explain my problem clearly (non-nativ-speaker, sorry). My Problem is: I'm not afraid of the CLIENTS, but of MYSELF. I'm afraid that someone uploads a VALID PDF which has an  EXE (or something else) in it, which opens a EXE/APP when I doubleclick on it.  My script allows PDF-Files, so a Hacker will be able to upload such files! I'm afraid that I (myself) doublclick the file and open the EXE on my server. (Of course I could open all PDFs on a virtual maschine, but how do I know/find out that the PDF has an exe in it)....

Comment: ...So it would have been better to ask you: HOW CAN I FILTER OUT A VALID PDF WHICH HAS AN EXE IT? I know/learned almost everything about file-upload-securing in the last few days, but I didn't find anything about how to find out if a valid PDF (or some other files) has an exe (or .app) in it. In your first point you mentioned "not accepting PDFs carrying such embedded code". So how do I manage to do this? (Thanks in advance!)

Comment: You mean you operate a _server_ with a graphical desktop meant for a _desktop_? What logic is _that_? Any why would you open a document from a specific upload folder if you are afraid to do so? Just don't! Why should you? As a last resort: remove read permission for the normal desktop user, there is absolutely no reasons why anyone doing normal operations on a server should or should be able to open documents uploaded by clients. Or at least define a save PDF interpreter on that system as standard application. One that does not simply execute any code in such files.

Comment: It strikes as a strange point of view to me to on the one hand operate a server and allow obviously _anyone_ to upload documents but then on the other hand be afraid of those documents again and wishing they were rendered useless.

Comment: About detecting such components in PDF documents: as said: first remove any PDF interpreter that stupid that it executes embedded code from such files. Then, use a utility like `pdftk` or similar to look into the details of a pdf without actually "opening" it as such. But that is not a real solution, since obviously you do not want to check each uploaded document manually (I still not understand why you are interested at all: just leave those documents alone and all is fine). Last, It certainly should be possible to detect such documents on a scripting base by means of regular expressions.

Comment: As I mentioned: I'm still LEARNING/TEACHING MYSELF all this server stuff. So I downloaded an installed WAMPP (which lets me do all the server related things graphically / on windows) and so I thought that when I buy/rent a provider-package the handling would be the same (GRAPHICALLY / LIKE WINDOWS (isn't it??)). Furthermore I could run a public server AT HOME (WAMPP or XAMPP). Then it also would be graphicLLY, wouldn't it??

Comment: Sure, that is possible from a technical point of view. _But_: why should you? It is much easier and generates much less load on the server to use not exactly MS-Windows as a server, what it never was meant to be. Other systems are far a better choice for such tasks. I'd say you have to decide yourself: learn a better environment (yes, not a little task, I know), or go with MS-Windows you are seemingly used to and accept all the threads it brings and invest endless time into trying to work around all those issues and dangers. Why do you think 97% of all web servers run Linux?

Comment: Well first: THANK YOU for your patience with me. I really apreciate it. And: You are absolutely right with using a LINUX-server for this (I promise I will, in about half a year, but I need a solution for now). For your understanding: The reason I want to open uploaded PDFs is, that people shall submit short-stories, which I (and the Community) can read and rate. That's why I have to open the files by myself (on my PC which also serves as the Server for the next 2 or 3 months). It's a great tipp to.........

Comment: .......... It's a great tipp to use a better/safer PDF-Interpreter, which I will (which one do you recommend). But with what RegEx or Lib can I FILTER OUT such files from the beginning.

Comment: I do not have such a pdf at hand, therefore I cannot take a look at it. You got one? If so: check its content (obviously _not_ using a PDF-Interpreter but something like a plain text editor or even a terminal pager). You should easily be able to tell apart the different objects inside the PDF structure apart (like images and fonts), and that way also executables or code in general should be easy to spot.

Comment: Well thanks again. But this is a Blacklist-Startegy (which can never be 100% sure). Aren't there other ways of PDF-cleaning. Like: Isn't there a PHP-Lib that copies just the VALID content of a PDF into a NEWLY CREATED PDF. (Like you can copy the graphical data of a JPG using PHP's "GD" to ensure that the NEWLY created JPG than has no more PHP anywhere in it). Isn't there such a library for PDF-cleanings.

Comment: Sorry, you are simply on the wrong track. You will _never_ really improve security as long as you build on an insecure base. MS-Windows based systems simply _are_ highly vulnerable to such threads compared to other systems. It make little sense to invest a huge effort into trying to improve that on your side, if the base does not get fixed. And the base will not get fixed, since MS does not have any interest in that.

Comment: Isn't the pdftk toolkit available for MS-Windows in the mean time? I think so. The Linux version is scriptable, you might want to give it a try. But as said: you will invest days of work chasing a goal you cannot really reach. http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Comment: As I said: I definitely will go learn Linux in the future. But as you said: This is not done in 1 day! Thats why for now I'm just looking for a PHP-Library to copy PDF-Text and -Pictures into a NEW/CLEAN PDF (just like I do it with gd or imagick on pictures). Do you know such a PHP-library?

Comment: No, and I doubt you will find a solution that produces "clean" PDFs for any document uploaded. The structure of PDFs generated by a multitude of applications for that purpose is simply to different to find an easy solution or strategy to do so. Too many different elements may occur, to many different structures. The most promising would be to print the PDF into a file using a virtual printer. But for this you would have to open it first, so you are back at sqaure one.

Comment: Except, it just occurs to me that _if_ you use an intelligent printing system (like for example CUPS), you might want to give this a try: that printing system accepts PDF documents and can forward them directly to a PDF capable printer. Now if you define a virtual printer that is able to print PDF documents, then the printing system does not require an insecure PDF interpreter like Adobe Reader but does the interpretation internally. That would be safer, you could even have the printing system on another system (virtual). It's just an idea...

Comment: Wow! Really cool idea! I think I'll give this a try in the next days and let you know if it worked. But for now: THANK YOU! REALLY! You really helped me a lot and I really apreciate your patience. I finally click the above sign to accept your answer now. You REALLY deserve it! Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, you are welcome and thanks for the feedback. I like tackling with ideas and issues, sostuff like this is kind of fun :-) One more thought: if the above idea is promising, then maybe print into a PS document instead of PDF. PS is easier (PDF was developed based in PS) and does not allow embedding of things like executable, since PostScript (PS) is a strict layout description language, not more. Most PDF interpreters can display PS, so this might be an even safer option.

Comment: Any progress? I remember printing PDF in massive numbers from within php years ago. Worked like charm even to printers across this republic and we even got fine statistics back then... We just fed the PDFs to `lpr` commands and referred to predefined printing queues in CUPS. However that was obviously CUPS running on Linux. Are `lpr` and colleagues available on MS-Windows? Does CUPS support virtual printers with PDF logic under MS-Windows?